# Adding values of column based on employee attendance

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with the following data

[image]

I need result something like below

The VBA code must consider code say 12 and add corresponding dates say 02-jan login hours, next it should add 03-jan hours. For example,
code 12->02-Jan = 08 and 03-Jan = 9. Then for code 15->02-Jan =6 and 03-Jan=8 Likewise it should repeat every code in a loop and put each result in another column. Is there a way to solve using excel VBA. All I have done is do for specific cells but unable to generalize.

Comment: You can achieve this using Pivot Table. Do you really want to write a VBA code for this?

Comment: You can do it by excel formula. First Extract all unique `Codes` from code column. Then put each date as column header. Use `SUMPRODUCT()` formula to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Thanks shrivallabha.redij and Harun24HR, but this is just a part of my problem. I need to do something else as well based on the outcome of this thing. SO VBA is must for me now